# Redirect to View based on value in Form (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm getting value from user in form like this

```py
#views.py

class DbTotsugoForm(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = DbTotsugoForm
    template_name = 'totsugo_app/db_totsugo_chose.html'
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('<app-name>:contact-us')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        file_type = form.cleaned_data['file_type'] # here I have a value from user (book, folder)
        return super(DbTotsugoForm, self).form_valid(form)
```

and I would like to redirect user to `list view` - a data from DB based on the value above like this

```py
class MYLook(ListView):
    template_name = 'totsugo_app/db_totsugo_list.html'
    # So based on `file_type` variable above I want to change `Book` to `Folder` here
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
```

How could I pass there that value, without creating `MYLook` two times for both values?

Comment: You want to change the ***QuerySet*** being used by the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do that. First, use URL Querystring to send the value from one view to another:

```
# in DbTotsugoForm view
def form_valid(self, form):
    file_type = form.cleaned_data['file_type'] # here I have a value from user (book, folder)
    return redirect("{}?fileType={}".format(reverse('<app-name>:contact-us'), file_type))

# in MYLook view

class MYLook(ListView):
    # ...

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
       file_type = self.request.GET.get('fileType', None)
       if file_type == 'Book':
          return Book.objects.all()
       return Folder.objects.all()
```

**(Alternative Solution)** you can use [`request.session`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/) to store the data. For example:

```
# in DbTotsugoForm view
def form_valid(self, form):
    file_type = form.cleaned_data['file_type'] # here I have a value from user (book, folder)
    self.request.session['file_type'] = file_type
    return super(DbTotsugoForm, self).form_valid(form)

# in MYLook view

class MYLook(ListView):
    # ...

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
       file_type = self.request.session.pop('file_type', None)
       if file_type == 'Book':
          return Book.objects.all()
       return Folder.objects.all()
```

FYI, you are using same name `DbTotsugoForm` for the form and view, you should change the name of the view to something else, ie `DbTotsugoView`.

Comment: this worked nice! thanks! I did it with the first way